# Mean value theorem and differentiability

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$, $a<b$ and let $f$ be differentiable real-valued function on an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that contains $[a,b].$ Show that if $\lambda$ is any real number between $f'(a)$ and $f'(b)$ then there exists a number $c\in(a,b)$ such that $\lambda = f'(c)$.

I know I have to combine the mean value theorem with the intermediate value theorem for the function $\frac{f(x_1)-f(x_2)}{x_1-x_2}$ on the set $\{ (x_1,x_2)\in E^2:a\le x_1<x_2 \le b\}.$ How can I do that?

Comment: This is Darboux theorem and mean value theorem is not to be used directly. Rather we need to use concept of local maximum/minimum as done in Nirdonkey's answer.

Comment: The proof sought by the original poster using the mean value theorem and the intermediate value theorem is presented in Lars Olsen's paper "A new proof of Darboux's theorem". Olsen also presents the more common proof by the extreme value theorem.
Link 1: http://www.jstor.org/stable/4145046?origin=JSTOR-pdf
Link 2: http://www.ime.usp.br/~oliveira/DARBOUXPROPERTY.pdf

Comment: The proof in Olsen's paper is not new, despite the title. It appears in Mathematical Analysis, 2e, by Apostol. See Theorem 5.16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we should add the condition that $f'(a)\ne f'(b)$, otherwise $f(x)=\sin x$, $a=-\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ and $b=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ would be a counterexample. Furthermore, $\lambda\ne f'(a)$ or $f'(b)$.

If we donote $g(x)=f(x)-\lambda x$, then the problem is equivalent to "If $f'(a)f'(b)<0$ then exists a $\nu\in(a,b)$, s.t. $f'(\nu)=0$".

Proof: Assume $f'(a)<0,f'(b)>0$, then $f(x)$ must reach its minimum value in $(a,b)$. This point $x=\nu$ has the property $f'(\nu)=0$. If $f'(a)>0,f'(b)<0$, then $f(x)$ must reach its maximum value in $(a,b)$. This point $x=\mu$ has the property $f'(\mu)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

We will first reduce this to the case where $\lambda=0$ by considering the function $g(x)=f(x)-\lambda x$.  Then $g'(a)$ and $g'(b)$ have opposite signs.  Without loss of generality assume that $g'(a)<0$ and $g'(b)>0$.  If $g(a)=g(b)$ we are done by the mean value theorem.  If $g(a)<g(b)$ we can use the fact that $\displaystyle\lim_{y\rightarrow a}\frac{g(y)-g(a)}{y-a}<0$ to find a $y$ so that $a<y$ and $g(y)<g(a)$.  We can now find a $c$ such that $c\in (g(a),g(y))$ and $c\in (g(y),g(b))$.  Then apply the intermediate value theorem to get $a^{*},b^{*}\in (a,b)$ that satisfy $a^{*}<b^{*}$ and $g(a^{*})=g(b^{*})=c$.  Finally apply the mean value theorem on the closed interval $[a^{*},b^{*}]$.  A similar argument can be made for the case of $g(a)>g(b)$.

Comment: Eric why would $g'(a)<0$ imply that there is a $y<a$ such that $g(y)<g(a)$?

Comment: $g'(a)<0$ means that $\displaystyle\lim_{y\rightarrow a^{+}}\frac{g(y)-g(a)}{y-a}=g'(a)<0$.  By the $\varepsilon-\delta$ limit definition, for $\varepsilon=\frac{-g'(a)}{2}$ we can find a $\delta$ so that if $|y-a|<\delta$ we have $\frac{g(y)-g(a)}{y-a}<g'(a)+\varepsilon=\frac{g'(a)}{2}<0$.  Because $y>a$, $y-a>0$ and by the above inequality we have $g(y)-g(a)<0$ and $g(y)<g(a)$.  I realize this is not what my original post said.  Sorry about that.  I have edited it to be correct.

Comment: Notice that the original statement was true, but it did not apply to this proof.

Comment: thanks for clarifying!